# Why VOLLEY retrieves the same data with differing parameters?

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley, response

I'm facing some kind of weird trouble with `volley`:

When I retrieve data with parameter `a` for the first time, there's nothing evil. However, all the next responses will be as same as the first one even though the parameter `a` is altered. Rerunning the app results all the mentioned. What could be the problem?

volley codes:

```
private void select() {
        Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            //someCodes    
            }
        };
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //someCodes
            }
        };
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "link", listener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("key", "value");
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity.this);
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

`

Also, some changes are exerted on my server host; respecting this issue which `php` versions are suitable for designing an android web service, due to such a log: `"stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.4.4)"` when downloading mp3 files which counters another kind of problem. could it be related to the volley issue?

php codes:

```
<?php
$a = $_REQUEST['key'];
try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=name;dbname=db", "sq", "aabsabss");
    $connection->exec('set names utf8');
    $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM  table WHERE cul = '$a'";
    $result = $connection->query($selectQuery);
    $outputArray = array();
    if ($result->rowCount()) {
        $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($rows as $resultArray) {
            $item = array();
            $item['a'] = $resultArray['a'];
            $item['b'] = $resultArray['b'];
            $item['c'] = $resultArray['c'];   
            $outputArray[] = $item;
        }
        echo json_encode($outputArray);
    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo $exception;
}
```

***Any help is appreciated.***

Comment: will you please post volley request and php source to let me take a look?

Comment: @RushikantPawar added ... thanks!

Comment: I added details, why is it still cloesd? pleassssssse?????

Comment: What is the volley version? And how or where you have placed it in project?

Comment: the version is 1.1.1. it takes a sharedpreference value from the previous activity and uses it as the key param. there's no problem with the sharedPreference; the values change but I just get the first response every time . . .

Comment: I am unable to post as it is legnthy and the question is closed too, the library you are using is latest. And it is working too,, I just want you to replace the JSON to StringRequest and on server side $item['a']  concatenate with UNDERSCORE with b with c.. Just give it a try, and use  request.setShouldCache(false);

Comment: First you try just with request.setShouldCache(false); if not worked then use a simple StringRequest with same flag and demand string from PHP by echo

Comment: wow, `request.setShouldCache(false);` just worked. thank you my friend, @RushikantPawar. that's was a help. also the question is opened, you can post your answer if you like to. but what's the issue? there was not such a problem till some changes in the host, as they sent me a ticket announcing the changes on their server . . ...

Comment: Android is officially from google as android is keeping changing over the time, they are changing volley too, as you and me are developers, volley does not bother os to make a new request every time, it just tells you and me that yes request is getting successful and prevents some code execution of volley classes, android classes and networking classes and android telephony classes and android microprocessors many tasks are avoided because of the which is why now a days battery performance has gone up. Its a headache for developers, tomorrow I will answer as it will help someone in future

Comment: yeah that's right. Thanks my friend . . .@RushikantPawar

Comment: abdad, Posted answer as your request. But it clearly indicates the googles awkward strategies giving pain to the freelance developers like me and others. It is full of negativity, hard work with no end result, and no one to care. To accept or not is solely your and communities choice, You can mark it negative too. I agree to all situations because as a developer i have no rights left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference : As per the request i am answering this question, so that in coming future if anyone come across this thread or issue, it might help them.

> Why VOLLEY retrieves the same data with differing parameters?

Answer is not as short as the question, as in the last 8-10 years, google libraries and google android has changed a lot over the time. The answer is mostly theoretical which will at least give some insights to the developers.

**1) I want to print hello world in everything as on startup**

Now the world is not like Language C and you compile hello world any time. Yes i understand the developers needs the hello world assistance as the startup point in everything and then they build the concepts and the whole architecture over it. But the system resources are not for such stupid things. System resources and battery performance is now the most important factor.

**2) Then when i can print hello world as starting point?**

When your app is actively running and if only it is open to the user. Even then with restrictions over it and with proper development strategies.

**3) What was the problem?**
Libraries are now AI enabled, which learns that this a repeating task and mostly previous result is getting used every time, so it never gives stress to the most of the system functionalities and saves the, time and resources of the system.

**4) What was the needed?**

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
```

**5) Is the problem solved now?**

**BIG NO.** Still the approach needs to be refined.

**6) Then how can i refine it?**

Avoid sending network requests like a child. Keeping requesting ALL THE TIME. Example : If you want to receive information about is your app user is registered or not then keep your own database day-wise. Remember if today have you requested it? If requested never request again for today. On tomorrow it will just request once and if requested already then on tomorrow it will never request again. Optimise it beyonf the limits of a single developer. So you must have 1000 developers..!!

**7) Why the problem is still not solved then?**

Look, you are no one special and android os is not for getting orders from your code and run it whenever you wants all the time..!! It will never run.

**8) But android is running this code every time when i requests?**
Because you are on emulator. But in market there is no android. 99% are modified ROM which are colorOs, OxygenOS, FunTouch OS, MUIUI, ... They just allows applications to run in the background if the apps are from google ( maps, business, play store ) or from facebook or whatsapp or twitter. Your app will never run once removed from recents.

**9) What i can do then**
Nothing if you are not a big business tycoon.